# White border line on Image using clipPath of fabricjs

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs, clip-path

I'm trying to clip image with clipPath object using fabricjs in Reactjs . It works fine except there is a white line (about 1 pixel) showing on top and left border. Code can be checked at this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-elbakyan-08hec?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, fabric objects have a transparent stroke of 1px. Setting a `strokeWidth` value of 0 on your clipPath object will get rid of this.

See http://fabricjs.com/fabric-gotchas